# how to linearly interpolate monthly data from the 15th of each month that rolls over the 15th of the next month

Tags: python, pandas, linear-interpolation

I have a monthly dataset that I want to interpolate daily. However I need to interpolate from the 15th of each month or midmonth (Jan 16th, Feb 14th, March 15th...), to the next one.

```
Here is my data set: 

2000-01-31  0.02451
2000-02-28  0.03392
2000-03-31  0.15451
2000-04-30  0.28366
2000-05-31  0.46806
2000-06-30  0.67766
...
```

First: I need these values to be set every mid-month.

```
2000-01-16  0.02451
2000-02-14  0.03392
2000-03-16  0.15451
2000-04-15  0.28366
2000-05-16  0.46806
2000-06-15  0.67766
```

Second: Then daily interpolate

```
2000-01-16  0.02451
2000-01-17
2000-01-18
...
2000-01-31
2000-02-01
2000-02-02
...

2000-02-14  0.03392
```

**I'm able to interpolate each month from the 1st to the 31st using the following code:**

```
### Linear interpolation from monthly values to daily
import pandas as pd

df.set_index(pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', end='1/1/2010', freq='M'), inplace=True, drop=True)
rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2000', end='1/1/2010', freq='D')
df2 = df.reindex(rng, axis=0).interpolate(axis=0)
```

**Results**

```
RESULTS                EXPECTED RESULTS 
2000-01-31  0.02451    2000-01-16   0.02451
2000-02-01  0.02485    2000-02-17   0.02485
2000-02-02  0.02518    2000-02-18   0.02518
...
2000-02-26  0.03325    2000-02-12   0.03325
2000-02-27  0.03359    2000-02-13   0.03359
2000-02-28  0.03392    2000-02-14   0.03392
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i would do:

```
# offset the timestamp
df[0] -= pd.to_timedelta(df[0].dt.day//2, unit='d')
```

which gives you

```
           0        1
0 2000-01-16  0.02451
1 2000-02-14  0.03392
2 2000-03-16  0.15451
3 2000-04-15  0.28366
4 2000-05-16  0.46806
5 2000-06-15  0.67766
```

and you can interpolate:

```
df.set_index(0).asfreq('D').interpolate()
```

Comment: Thank you so so much :)